# Tensorflow is installed in the conda environment, but I can't access any of its attribute functions

Tags: python, tensorflow, terminal, anaconda

I have set up a virtual environment using anaconda, and I have successfully installed the relevant libraries to set up tensorflow.

The commands that I ran are:

```
conda activate tf
conda install -c anaconda tensorflow
```

The code that I am trying to run is:

```
import tensorflow as tf
print("Hello, Tensorflow!")
print(tf.__version__)
```

And I get the following error:

Hello, Tensorflow!
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Users\cocoh\OneDrive\Documents\Coding\MI\ForestCover\TensorflowTest.py", line 3, in 
print(tf.**version**)
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute '**version**'

Calling `pip show tensorflow` shows that tensorflow is in fact, installed in the environment:

```
Name: tensorflow
Version: 2.11.0
Summary: TensorFlow is an open source machine learning framework for everyone.
Home-page: https://www.tensorflow.org/
Author: Google Inc.
Author-email: packages@tensorflow.org
License: Apache 2.0
Location: c:\users\cocoh\anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages
Requires: tensorflow-intel
Required-by:
```

I'm not sure what the issue is, and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: do you have a file called tensorflow.py in the same folder?

Comment: Do you have a python code file named `tensorflow.py` in the same directory as your test file?

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy, I do not have such a file name. Calling 'ls' in my working directory prints the following in the terminal: 
----                 -------------         ------ ----
-a---l        2023-03-04   9:46 PM           1230 FC.py
-a---l        2023-03-04   9:23 PM             75 TensorflowTest.py

Answer (score 0):

Please try again the below code to install `TensorFlow`. Also make sure you have installed the correct `TensorFlow` version compatible with the installed `python` version in your system as per this tested [build configurations](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows#tested_build_configurations).

```
conda install tensorflow #or

pip install tensorflow
```

Please follow the step by step instructions in this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#step-by-step_instructions) for more details on tensorflow installation. Let us know if the issue still persists.